# Memory leak: verify block type

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I meet a memory leak problem and the minimum code as follows. My compiler is VS2008.

```
//haar.h
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

class HaarClass
{
public:

    HaarClass(void);
    ~HaarClass(void);

    void Memory_Leak_Test();

private:
    long* feature_vector_;
};


HaarClass::HaarClass(void)
{
    feature_vector_ = NULL;
}

HaarClass::~HaarClass(void)
{
    if (feature_vector_ != NULL) {
        delete[] feature_vector_;
    }
}

void HaarClass::Memory_Leak_Test(){

    if (feature_vector_!=NULL) {
        delete[] feature_vector_; 
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        feature_vector_ = new long[100];

        if (feature_vector_!=NULL) {
            delete[] feature_vector_; 
        }

    }

}
```

And the main file is

```
//main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "haar.h"  

int main()
{
    HaarClass a;
    a.Memory_Leak_Test();

    return 0;
}
```

And the error or alert is

> _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));

in dbgdel.cpp Line: 52.

Therefore, what's the error? Thanks.

Comment: The code that's shown in this question fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve]. Unless this question gets edited, and a [mcve] is provided, no answer will be possible.

Comment: `if (feature_vector_!=NULL)` -- What compiler are you using?  If `new[]` fails, a `std::bad_alloc` exception is thrown, and not a NULL is returned.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is the purpose of the first `if (feature_vector_!=NULL) { delete[] feature_vector_; }`? is `feature_vector_` initialized to `NULL` or pointer to buffer allocated and not deleted properly before calling this function?

Comment: And why the `new[] / delete[]` gymnastics anyway?  Just use `std::vector<long> feature_vector_;` and simply call `vector::resize()` if the size needs to be increased / decreased.

Comment: Try doing: `new (std::nothrow) long[number_of_feature_]` instead.

Comment: I use VS2008, and long* feature_vector_; is defined as a private member in class "HaarFeature3DClass".

Comment: @Lee -- VS 2008 has a functional STL implementation.  No need to be using raw pointers.  But you still haven't posted an [mcve].

Comment: @Lee -- You seem to be under the impression that wherever the assert occurs is where the problem starts.  That is not the case.  That's why you need to show us the [mcve] we've been asking for.  You could be doing all sorts of things before this code is executed that could cause the error.

Comment: No, that is not a [mcve].  Where in what you posted is **complete**?  "Complete" means we can take the code, compile it, run it, and see the error without having to add, remove, change, etc. a single line of code.

Comment: You're writing to memory outside the block that's been allocated, most likely before it (e.g. `feature_vector_[-1]`).  It's detected in the destructor for `feature_class` when it tries to delete the allocated pointers.  You're not NULLing out `feature_vector_` after you delete it, so this might also be due to a double free (not sure if VS detects that differently).

Comment: @Lee You need to show us the constructor and destructor for your class.  Otherwise the code you posted shows you calling `delete[]` on a pointer that may not have been initialized.

Comment: @Lee -- [This is a complete example that duplicates a similar issue.](http://ideone.com/PUXQaE).  The error in this example is caused by what 1201ProgramAlarm mentioned.  If you had used `std::vector`, not only would this problem never had shown up, more than likely your program would run faster, since you wouldn't be calling `new[]` and `delete[]` so many times in a loop, and instead `resize()` would just be called.  The `resize()` is much smarter in memory management than calling the `new / delete` so many times.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie At present, is it a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How to revise the code using `std::vector` and `resize()` ?

Comment: @Lee [See this example](http://ideone.com/9uopP9).  Here is the difference between your code and the code at the link -- while your code basically "does nothing", it still is doing a lot of work by repeatedly calling `new` and `delete`.  The code at the link does the resize() at the beginning, and calling resize() over and over again in the loop *does nothing*.  Why?  The reason is that `vector::resize` is smart enough to know that there already memory allocated to fit the data, so there is no need to reallocate.  That's why the `vector::resize` will run faster than your code.

Comment: @Lee -- (continued).   Also note the lack of a destructor and the constructor is empty.  No crashes, no need to set things to `NULL`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete the pointer in your `Memory_Leak_Test` you do not set the pointer to NULL so your destructor will try to delete it again

```
void HaarClass::Memory_Leak_Test(){

    if (feature_vector_!=NULL) {
        delete[] feature_vector_; 
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        feature_vector_ = new long[100];

        if (feature_vector_!=NULL) {
            delete[] feature_vector_; 
            feature_vector = NULL;    // <<-----
        }

    }

}
```